# MySQL cannot run query for time restriction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I have a MySQL query I am running on my website that is like:

```
SELECT
    [random columns]
FROM
    DB_Name
WHERE
    EndDate > unix_timestamp(now())
    AND StartDate <= UTC_DATE()
```

In my Database EndDate is the epoch date and StartDate is the date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Running this query is totally fine and it is able to run in like 0.1seconds. The `WHERE` clauses shows rows that have already started but are ending in the future.

I have a section of my website that specifically shows rows that are ending in the next 24hours. So I change the `EndDate` filter to be `EndDate <= unix_timestamp(now() + interval 1 day) AND StartDate <= UTC_DATE()` but this makes the query take several minutes.

Running `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB_Name WHERE EndDate` filter to be `EndDate <= unix_timestamp(now() + interval 1 day)` returns ~400K rows. By comparison, there are only 3K rows for `WHERE EndDate > unix_timestamp(now() + interval 1 day)`

Is there a faster way to make this comparison without it taking minutes to complete?

Comment: What data type is `EndDate`? If it's a `Date` (as opposed to `INT`), why are you comparing it to the result of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: `EndDate` is of type `INT(11)`

Comment: Yet `StartDate` is of type `Date`? Why the mix?

Comment: Would it make much of a difference to have `EndDate` be of type `Date`?

Comment: You likely want unix_timestamp(utc_timestamp()), not now; now uses the timezone set by the client

Comment: It is grossly confusing to use two different ways to represent date&time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think u need this SQL, if u need filter further end strict in 1 day:

```
SELECT
    [random columns]
FROM
    DB_Name
WHERE
    EndDate > unix_timestamp(now())
    AND EndDate <= unix_timestamp(now() + interval 1 day)
    AND StartDate <= UTC_DATE()
```

Comment: Duh, forgot I still had to keep the `EndDate > unix_timestamp(now())` filter. Thank you.